# mod_rewrite to return files if existent, CMS if not

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get `mod_rewrite` to look in a content directory for a file and call my CMS if it can't find it, but I can't get it to work. I've tried several answers to similar questions on here, but none seems to work properly.

My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/content/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/content/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I thought that adding the `[L]` suffix to my first rule meant that it wouldn't execute further rules, but it seems to call my CMS regardless of the presence or absence of a file. If I comment out the second rule, files are returned but obviously the CMS isn't. I also tried adding

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/content/$1 !-f
```

before the second rule, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

I'd also like to check for whether the directory exists (ie `-d`), but I've not put that code in yet since I can't even get files to work!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^content/ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/content/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/content/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /content/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [QSA,L]
```